# Google Sheets Query multiple range

Tags: google-sheets

I have this query function, which tries to get rows from different sheets, but it gives me an error and I can't figure out why. Can you please help me with this?

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A2:F;Sheet3!A2:F}, "SELECT * WHERE COL1 "&A2&" '"&B2&"'")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here. Do you want to concatenate the values in A2 and B2 and return the rows that have that concatenated string in Col1 ? Are you looking for an exact match ? Maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi!
Sorry if I was not clear. So in Sheet1 cellA2 I have a dropdown with these values: "contains,starts with,ends with,matches,like" and in Sheet1 cell B2 I have the search term. I have rows in Sheet 2 and Sheet3 and I like to show the results in Sheet1. Is this more clear? If not please tell and I try to explain it differently. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A2:F;Sheet3!A2:F}; "SELECT * WHERE Col1 "&A2&" '"&B2&"'")
```

and see if that works?

(Note the proper case in "Col1")

If you'd want to make the search case-insensitive try

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(LOWER({Sheet2!A2:F;Sheet3!A2:F}); "SELECT * WHERE Col1 "&A2&" '"&B2&"'"))
```

Comment: Hi!
Yes that was an error you are right, however it did not fix the error sadly.
But thank you for noticing!

Comment: I did a quick test and the formula worked for me. Can you maybe set up a test sheet (with realistic looking data)?

Comment: Hi you can find it here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1puWEiRAi0VYWZ6ysHWekmN-yuXpu8VAG4KCnnubO_io/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't access the spreadsheet. Can you fix permissions (change to: anyone with the link can edit) ?

Comment: Should be ok now.

Comment: Still can't acces. If you are on a domain, it might be a domain setting that blocks sharing outside the domain?

Comment: Sorry, now it should be ok.

Comment: Your locale requires the use of semi-colons in formulas. Secondly the search is case-sensitive. So 'test' will return no results, but 'Test' will return 2 rows.